Is it possible to load configs from a file for a "dynamic config group" in Hydra?
Imagine a complex config that specifies many ML models, each with some number of layers. Something like
@dataclass
class Layer:
   width: int
   activation: str
   ...

@dataclass
class Model:
   layers: List[Layer]

@dataclass
class Forest:
   models: Dict[str, Model]

Then, I have a yaml file as my main config where I define a forest of models. Then, on command line, I can override individual fields of some layer with something like models.cnn.layers.1.width=10. I would like to have a directory of various layers and be able to do something like models.cnn.layers.1=wide_cnn on command line, where wide_cnn.yaml is some yaml file in that directory.
I tried various things like using wide_cnn.yaml, using absolute path, using models/cnn/layers.1, etc. It seems like the core issue is that to have hydra load a file, the text before the = on command line (call it a "key") must be a config group. I don't quite understand what makes something a config group, but it seems like it corresponds to a directory structure. In my case, the key can be basically anything because users can name their models arbitrarily.
Any suggestions how to do something like this? Thanks!

Recommend using python lib, Pydantic instead of dataclasses. Its very popular lib that comes with built in tools that could help.

Hydra comes pretty close, but list composition is not supported.
In general, this is pushing Hydra to its limits, and I am not sure it can be done conveniently.
You can "assign a config file" only if it's a part of a config group.
You can also "assign a list of config files" to use to compose a dictionary,
You can specify a top-level model config file that includes multiple config files from the same config group.
(Note: this will create a dictionary of layers, not a list of layers).
Something like this:
model/
  model1.yaml
  model2.yaml
  layers/
    layer1.yaml
    layer2.yaml
    layer3.yaml

model1.yaml
defaults:
  - layers:
    - layer1
    - layer3

model2.yaml
defaults:
  - layers:
    - layer2
    - layer3

Note that layer files needs to specify a sub node otherwise they will all write be merged into the same node. You can achieve it by changing their structure or overriding the package in the defaults list).

Thanks for such a quick answer! If we ignore the list composition not being supported and assume that layers are a dictionary. Or even simpler, can I "assign a model from a file on command line", e.g. models.cnn=my_cnn. All the cases I have seen of config groups, their names are static and the yamls must be in corresponding directories. In this case, models is a dictionary, users can freely choose model names, and want to load the config from some file that is not in the correspondingly-named directory. Is this possible?

See the package link above to for how to change the target node of a config. The syntax in the command line is something like config_group@package=config_file, where package is the location in the config tree.
